# What Tool or System Can I Use To Run R code

Tags: r

I need to mine some data from a PDF. For this, I have written some `R code` and saved it as `My_Code.R`) about 80-90 lines. What is the best tool or software that I can access in order to run 'R-code'.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Thanks,
Chaitu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RScript` command to run (wait for it) an `R` script.

e.g.

On Windows

```
Rscript.exe My_Code.R
```

On Linux/Mac

```
Rscript My_Code.R
```

You need to make sure `Rscript` in available in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: +1! but I think you have the same syntax in windows also ( no need for the exe extension).

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: RStudio**

In terms of a general tool for running R code, have you tried RStudio: https://www.rstudio.com/

As they note on the site, the "RStudio IDE is a powerful and productive user interface for R. It’s free and open source, and works great on Windows, Mac, and Linux." I use RStudio, as well as other IDE's, including Eclipse, nearly every day at work. Here is a quick screenshot of RStudio in action:

[image]

Of course, to run RStudio, you will need to install R. You can get more information on R here: http://www.r-project.org/

**Option 2: R Command Line**

As an alternative, you could simply run your R script on the command line in R using the call:

`source("filename.r")` to run your code.

**Option 3: Path Variable**

Assuming that you changed your path variable, you could also run a source R file using the following call:

```
r -f filename.r
```

You might want to also consult [a great resource here which gives lots of information about running R from the command line](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line).